# Which is the right Gulp and Sass packages from NPM?

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

Apologies if this is a stupid question. I've been following a tutorial on how to use NPM. Im at the point where it demonstrates how to use package management. It says to choose a package from the NPM website and install it by typing:

```
npm install <package>
```

Fair enough. I thought I would start with Gulp. I type that in the search bar and am presented with 14358 results. None of which is called just 'Gulp'. Same with Sass.

So, which is the right package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gulp docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) have all you need.

Gulp is:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Sass is:

```
npm install gulp-sass
```

Other plugins are on the [Gulp plugins](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/) site.